# Create SDK (or Library) from existing Android App (APK) that can be included in other Android Apps

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, shared-libraries, apk

I have an existing Android App that we now want to leverage as an SDK (or whatever is the equivalent on Android, a library?), so that the application could be included in another Android App as a library.

The concept is that we provide a "wrapper" class that customers make calls to, which would then interface with the existing code to do the functions, display stuff and do the work  our App generally does.

My hope is to be able to not have to move code around and just create a wrapper/SDK/Library interface which I can just build differently in gradle, and the result of that (a Library object?) would be given to the customer to include into their App.

Hope I am making sense. If you need more info I can give a high level example of what the App is doing.